# How does autoreload work with jupyter?

Tags: python, ipython, python-module, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a file `mytest.py` in the working directory, with the following content:

```
class MyTest(object):

  def __init__(self):
    print(1)
    pass
```

In `jupyter` I have these cells.

Cell 1:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import mytest
```

Cell 2:

```
x = mytest.MyTest()
```

If I start with a fresh kernel then it works as expected, and it gives me `1`. Now if I go into `mytest.py` and change the print out to 2 and rerun Cell 2 I would get:

```
1
[autoreload of mytest failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 247, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
]
[autoreload of mytest failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 247, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
]
```

If I run Cell 2 again now I'd get just `1` without any errors, but it still has not used the new code.

I can't figure out how to reload the module properly without restarting the kernel, which I can't do because I have some very time-consuming code in the real program.

I have tried this in `IPython` in terminal. Although instantiating the class after modifying the code also gives me errors (note that it's a different error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`) but it would use the updated code if I run it again. So it seems to me that this is a problem specific to `jupyter`.

What should I do to fix this?

EDIT (adding version info):
Anaconda 2.5.0
Python 3.5.0
IPython 4.1.2
jupyter 4.1.0
Mac OS X 10.11.2

Comment: What version of IPython are you running? If it's up to date, please file a bug about this. Autoreload is purely an IPython thing - Jupyter is the language agnostic pieces like the notebook interface, and it doesn't know what modules the kernel is loading.

Comment: @ThomasK I just added the version info. I do have the latest stable version of IPython. I feel like if this is indeed an IPython bug someone else would have run into this before I did. My set up is pretty vanilla though.

Comment: I'm not sure how either error could occur - I don't think we've seen them before. But you're not doing anything obviously wrong with autoreload, so maybe you're just the first to see that bug for some reason.

Comment: I found that the error is caused by having

    `c.InteractiveShell.deep_reload = True`

in `ipython_config.py`. Commenting it out fixed the problem in both IPython (in Terminal) and jupyter.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, Python 3.5.2, IPython 4.2 / 5.0.0, Mac OSX 10.11.6. I've got 
`c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']`
`c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']` in my ipython_config.py, which should be similar to your jupyter configuration. However, in my config the above fix was commented out anyway. Do you have any follow up info on this?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Python 2.7. Error message:

[autoreload of hsf.core failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 247, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
AttributeError: __abstractmethods__
] The line with deep_reload in my config is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of Jupyter (notebook v7.0.4, ipython v8.15.0), and I can say that now `autoreload` works just fine (can't reproduce the error mentioned in the question). In fact, after changing the content of `mytest.py`, if I re-run cell 2 then I get no errors and I can see the updated output.

Comment: I think this was fixed for me a couple of years ago. I don't remember what version though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your python and jupyter notbook version.

use this version of python: Python 3.9.17
and this version of notebook: 6.4.5

it will solve your problem.

Comment: These two recommended items are both pretty old tech at this point. At this point if you want the old version of Jupyter Notebook, you should be using 6.5x or NbClassic, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55)  for more background. And and [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf) for more about Jupyter Notebook 7+ which is the future of the document-centric interface. By the way, modern well-installed Python and Jupyter combinations should work, and Riccardo Bucco's answer is more in line with this point.